# get data onActivityResult from another application

Tags: java, android, package, onactivityresult

I have two application A and B.

Application A

the following code I launch B Application for get Result from A application activity ..

```
   String packageName = "com.cm.applicationb";
            PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
            Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            i.putExtra("grand_total", "2500");
            i.setAction(packageName);
            startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_DATA);
```

From Application A call onActivityResutl

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_DATA)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            me=data.getStringExtra("Obj");
        }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),me,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

B Application setResult Data

```
     Intent i=new Intent();
                i.putExtra("Obj", "object");
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
                finish();
```

Ever retrun null data and resultcode from onActivityResult. How we can solve it? It is impossible get data onAcitivityResult from another applicaion setREsult. Anyone please help me for us. Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no, I not getting error something but i get all null data and result code OnActivityResult.

Comment: Can you post full code for `B Application` where you are adding data. have you override "onBackPressed` in `B`?

Comment: @RohitArya , Yes I already have override "onBackPressed" and already test onCreate method in B, It is not okay pls help and share me if you have somthing ideia

Comment: post full code of `B`

Comment: Or just post the code of `onBackPressed`

Comment: @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent i=new Intent();
        i.putExtra("Obj", "Obj_Data");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();

    }

Comment: How did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `finish()` and call like this in `B`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 
    Intent data = new Intent();

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("Obj", "Obj_Data");
    data.putExtras(bundle);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
    super.onBackPressed(); // this calls finish(); internally.
}
```

Comment: Not okay yet now ... ('

Comment: This is work in the one app different activity. Does not  work different application.

Comment: @JOKEY Should work everywhere. There might be a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

just add this line to your manifest.xml

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

for more detail, check [this links](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive) that explain about how to receive data from other application